# Thermostat keeps switching on aux heat unnecessarily

Tags: thermostat, heat-pump

I have a basic dumb Honeywell thermostat (TH5220D) that very eagarly switches to aux heat (electric) when set above 73˚F, despite outdoor temperatures being nowhere near low enough to preclude efficient heating by heat pump. How do I make this stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for a technical manual, I found one at:

- http://www.bardhvac.com/digcat/s3364_techdoc_cd/TechDoc-PDF/8403-058_TH5220D_Installation_Guide_69-1783.pdf

By holding Fan and Up, one can access a setup menu that allows tuning a number of features. The most likely fix is function 26:

> Auxiliary heat control
>
> - 0 Comfort  **See page 14
> - 1 Economy

And on page 14:

> Auxiliary heat control (Setup Function 26)
>
> Systems  with  heat  pumps  can  be  set  to  operate  in  one  of  two  ways:
>
> Comfort Setting: The thermostat will prioritize comfort over economy
> depending on heat pump performance, load conditions and whether  the
> equipment  is  calling  for  heat. Raising  the  temperature  just  a  few degrees will often activate auxiliary heat.
>
> Economy Setting: The thermostat will attempt to reach the temperature set-
> ting without activating auxiliary heat. The thermostat waits a preset time
> before allowing auxiliary heat to be activated depending on the compressor stage performance, and on how many degrees the temperature setpoint is
> changed.

If this does not suffice to fix it, function 1 provides a huge hammer. Changing the system type from 5 (cooling+heat pump with aux heat) to 1 (cooling+heat pump only) will disable use of aux heat entirely, but will require switching back under circumstances where aux/emergency heat is really needed.

Comment: Where did you find this technical manual for the thermostat? I have a similar issue with my Honeywell RTH9585WF1012 and I'd like to know if the confort/economy option exists or any better option. For now, I went with disabling W2/Aux/E heat completely.

Comment: @jmbouffard: I googled the model number TH5220D I found on the back of it along with something like "technical manual" or "installation manual".